# Snowflake: is it ever okay to run infinite loops? I need to track changes from a table every second

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My use case is that I need to track all the changes (insertions/updates/deletions) from a table.

My idea is to create a stream on that table, and consume that stream every second or so, exporting all the changes to another history table (`mytable_history`).

A task would be the perfect candidate for that. But unfortunately, a task can only be scheduled for 1 minute or more. I'll be getting same-row updates per second, so I'd really need the task to run every second at least.

My idea now is to run an infinite `LOOP`, using `SYSTEM$WAIT` to consume the stream every 1 second and inserting the data to the history table.

Is this a bad idea? What could go wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Curious if you ever implemented this? Thinking of doing something similar. With Marcel's point below the idea would be to commit each run, wait a few seconds and go again

Answer (score 0):

I can add two points to your idea:

- Please note that "DML updates to the source object in parallel transactions are tracked by the change tracking system but do not update the stream until the explicit transaction statement is committed and the existing change data is consumed." (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams-intro.html#table-versioning)
- Your warehouse would run all day to process this, that's why your costs would increase noticeable.